# Proving the equality of two fractions

Tags: proof-verification, fractions

We say two fractions a/b and c/d are equivalent if and only if a*d=c*b
An example on that: 2/4 = 1/2 because 2*2=1*4

But is there another way to prove this operation in general? not by samples of examples

Comment: Not following.  If you just mean this as a definition, then what is there to prove?   If "equivalent" means "equal as rational numbers"  then it follows from cross-multiplication.  (multiply both sides of the equality by $bd$).

Comment: @lulu What I mean is why does the equivalence of fractions imply the cross-multiplication operation?

Comment: Once again, you need to say what you mean by equivalence.  Some people use what you wrote as a definition.  That makes sense, but then there is nothing to prove.  If, on the other hand, you already have a notion of the rationals and arithmetic on the rationals then $\frac ab=\frac cd\implies bd\times \frac ab=bd \times \frac cd\implies ad=bc$.

Comment: Because a fraction $a/b$ is defined as such value $f$, which satisfies $fb=a$...? Then $f=g$ for $g=c/d$ iff $fd=c$. Multiply both sides by $b$ and you get $fbd=cb$, but on the LHS we have $fb=a$, so finally $ad=cb$.

Comment: @lulu thank you, I got it when you multiplied with bd on both sides

Comment: @CiaPan thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real question is "what is a fraction?" Once you resolve that, things get easy.

The axioms of real numbers say that for any number $x \ne 0$, there's another number (written $x^{-1}$) with the property that 
$$
x \cdot x^{-1} = x^{-1} \cdot x = 1 .
$$
That number's called the "multiplicative inverse" of $x$.

Now what does $\frac{a}{b}$ denote? It denotes the number
$$
a\cdot b^{-1}.
$$

OK, so let's suppose that 
$$
\frac{a}{b}  = \frac{c}{d}
$$
Translated, that means that 
$$
ab^{-1} = c d^{-1}
$$
We can multiply both sides by $b$ to get
$$
a b^{-1}b = c d^{-1} b
$$
Then we can use the fact that $b^{-1}b = 1$ to say that 
$$
a = c d^{-1} b
$$
Now we can swap the last two factors and say 
$$
a = c b d^{-1}
$$
and then we can multiply both sides by $d$ to get
$$
ad = c b d^{-1}d
$$
and finally use the fact that $d^{-1}d = 1$ to write
$$
ad = cb 1 = cb
$$
So that's a proof that if the fractions are equal, then $ad = cb$. (Hidden in there were applications of the associativity and commutativity of multiplication, and the fact that $1$ is the multiplicative identity, 
but I wanted to keep things simple.)

Note that my use of $x^{-1}$ didn't have anything to do with exponents per se. It's just a symbol denoting "the unique number which, when multiplied by $x$, gives the number $1$." I could have used some notation like $x'$ instead.

[To really complete things, I should write another proof that if $ad = bc$, and $b$ and $d$ are nonzero, then $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$, but that proof is roughly just the proof I gave, read from bottom to top.]

Comment: Thank you @John

Comment: How can I prove b/b =1 using the method used in this answer ?

Comment: Since $x/y$ is defined to be $x \cdot y^{-1}$, we have $b/ b = b \cdot b^{-1}$. And by the definition of $b^{-1}$, we know that $b^{-1} \cdot b = b \cdpt b^{-1} = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to prove the following proposition:
$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d} \text{ iff } ad = bc$$
Then you can just do this:
Let $a,b,c,d$ be arbitrary such that $b,d\neq 0$. Then

$\begin{align}
\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d} &\Leftrightarrow bd\Big(\frac{a}{b}\Big)=bd\Big(\frac{c}{d}\Big)\\
&\Leftrightarrow d\Big(\frac{a}{1}\Big)=b\Big(\frac{c}{1}\Big)\\
&\Leftrightarrow ad = bc \ \ \ \ \square
\end{align}
$

Comment: The left-facing arrow in the second equivalence is only valid if $b$ and $d$ are both nonzero, for otherwise they are not guaranteed to have multiplicative inverses (i.e., the simple "rule" that $\frac{b}{b} = 1$, which you've used implicitly, will not be true).

Comment: Also: you probably shouldn't be assuming that $a,b,c,d$ are *integers*; after all, $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi} = \frac{3\sqrt{2}}{3\pi}$.

Comment: @ericeschnei Thank you.